# Documentation is missing "awarded" sort on /me/badges

Tags: bug, api

I would have expected `/me/badges` to work in the same way as the `/users/{ids}/badges` version.
But there is no “awarded” sort on this page in the docs.

As it is actually working using an awarded sort, I suspect this to be a bug in the documentation.

It was just annoying for me, as it took quite a while to figure it out, as I just needed the “me” version.